# How do I create a correctly scaled x-axis?

Tags: axis, highcharts, data-visualization

I'm using HighCharts line plots where my x-axis data is unevenly distributed:

```
[4, 10, 40, 100, 400, 1000, etc.]
```

Currently the x-values are placed evenly.  I want the distance between x[5] and x[4] to be 10 times that between x[3] and x[2](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis).  How do I do this?

---

In the [GoogleCharts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes.html#Discrete_vs_Continuous) lingo, I need a **continuous** axis.

---

In [the docs](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis), I only see "linear", "logarithmic", and "datetime" for the axis type.  ("linear" is the default and does not do what I want).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't post your javascript generating the charts I'll have to guess, but I assume you are using `categories` within your `xAxis`. The categories are evenly distributed, so don't use them in this case.

If you change your `series` data block to specify `x` and `y` values (http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data example 2) the `xAxis` will show correct proportions for your values. For example look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays/).